# Add additional fields to Linq group by

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the LINQ to SQL as below, which works fine.

```
        var qry = (from h in dc.Timesheets
                   join s in dc.Users on h.UserID equals s.UserID
                   join ug in dc.UserGroups on s.UserGroupID equals ug.UserGroupID
                   where h.BookedOn >= _dateFrom.Value && h.BookedOn <= _dateTo.Value
                   group h by ug.UserGroupID into g
                   orderby g.Count() descending
                   select new
                   {
                       UserGroupingID = g.Key,
                       BookingsPerDay = g.Count() / days
                   }).ToList();
```

Now I want to add the name of the User Group, but somehow I struggle to get the LINQ right.
My limited knowledge tells me I should add the Description to the Group clause as follow, but it's a no-go:

I try:

```
    var qry = (from h in dc.Timesheets
               join s in dc.Users on h.UserID equals s.UserID
               join ug in dc.UserGroups on s.UserGroupID equals ug.UserGroupID
               where h.BookedOn >= _dateFrom.Value && h.BookedOn <= _dateTo.Value
               group h, GroupDescription = ug.Description by ug.UserGroupID into g
               orderby g.Count() descending
               select new
               {
                   UserGroupingID = g.Key,
                   Description = g.Key.GroupDescription
                   BookingsPerDay = g.Count() / days
               }).ToList();
```

> Error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not
>   a delegate type

Answer (score 1):

I think you might missing the new keyword here!!

```
 var qry = (from h in dc.Timesheets
           join s in dc.Users on h.UserID equals s.UserID
           join ug in dc.UserGroups on s.UserGroupID equals ug.UserGroupID
           where h.BookedOn >= _dateFrom.Value && h.BookedOn <= _dateTo.Value
           group new {h, GroupDescription = ug.Description} by new {GroupDescription} into g
           orderby g.Count() descending
           select new
           {
               UserGroupingID = g.Key,
               Description = g.Key.GroupDescription
               BookingsPerDay = g.Count() / days
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: The `by new {ug.UserGroupID}` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, the new in the group new {..} does not give a compile error, but in the select new I can't use ...g.Key.GroupDescription.  
Says it does not contain a definition for GroupDescription.

Comment: After the edit it's now `by new {GroupDescription}`. It still doesn't make sense to create an anonymous type with only one property. Just use `by GroupDescription`. Only create an anonymous type if you need more than one property, like `new {UserGroupId, GroupDescription}`

Comment: @user1208908 Whatever you write after the `by` keyword will be your `g.Key`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be an `==` for the `GroupDescription`? And aren't you missing a comma in the `select new` statement?

Comment: Yes, I am missing the comma in the select.  Saw it afterwards.  But no, the == in the select won't work.